# how do I solved a super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type type error?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a test on my app's index.html and here I have:

**test.py**

```
class IndexTest(TestCase):
 def setUp(self):
  url = reverse ('index')
  self.response = self.client_class.get(self, url)
```

and I get this traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
...
File "...\django\test\client.py", line 836, in get 
response = super().get(path, data=data, secure=secure, **extra)
TypeError: super(type, obj), obj must be an instance or a subtype of type
```

I don't know how to go about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that you are setting any not-standard Class, so you should not use `self.client_class`. Just change it to more standard way:

```
from django.test import Client

class IndexTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        url = reverse ('index')
        self.client = Client()
        self.response = self.client.get(self, url)
```